# CSS HTML: Centering divs

Tags: css, html

This should be a no brainer but I have a small mystery with the CSS for a pair of divs.  Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="centered" id="selectReport">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="p0" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="viewReport" runat="server" Text="View Report" OnClick="ViewReport" />
</div>
<div>
    ...a centered table...
</div>
<div class="centered" id="buttons">
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="saveEdits" Text="Save Edits" OnClick="SaveEdits_Click" />
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="redoEdits" Text="Redo Edits" OnClick="RedoEdits_Click" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
```

If I put this CSS in the same file:

```
<style>
    .centered
    {
        margin: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Both of the divs are left justified.

However if I put this CSS in a separate file:

```
.centered
{
    margin: auto;
}
```

the first div is left justified while the second div is centered.  I also tried writing identical CSS for each div id with the same results -- the first one is left justified while the second is centered.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

And here is the rendered HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><title>
Network Operations Dashboard
</title>
<link href="NetworkOperations.css" rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head>

<body>
<h1 style="text-align: center; font-size: 30pt" >Network Operations Dashboard</h1>
<form method="post" action="NetworkOperationsReport.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTAyNTkyMjcyNw9kFgICAw9kFgQCAQ8QDxYGHgxBdXRvUG9zdEJhY2tnHg1EYXRhVGV4dEZpZWxkBQ9BcmNoaXZlRmlsZU5hbWUeC18hRGF0YUJvdW5kZ2QQFQYURGFzaGJvYXJkXzIwMTItTWF5LTEGVHJlbmRzBlN0eWxlcwdTY3JpcHRzCEFwcF9EYXRhB0FjY291bnQVBhREYXNoYm9hcmRfMjAxMi1NYXktMQZUcmVuZHMGU3R5bGVzB1NjcmlwdHMIQXBwX0RhdGEHQWNjb3VudBQrAwZnZ2dnZ2dkZAIFDxYCHgdWaXNpYmxlaGRkUrfXkiabK3mrjfzXNLtumhzsq/lXy+2nab/n0oCTc60=" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.form1;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>


<script src="/WebApp/WebResource.axd?d=J72WHhxz11o7F4T65-nk2s6O8A5yTLJdKan5j1GWRlsyEEDvOExumPz8U-TIG_EGGghKU7cpVHXCxLarpokjZhHzOtYqhdwyIhY1CB4wM9o1&amp;t=634746614287359483" type="text/javascript"></script>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

<input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONX" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" id="__SCROLLPOSITIONY" value="0" />
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEWCwLY4tiyDgLwppLRBwKPpuCFAgLH2cPODQLV24ysCQLizdSlDwKFsO2xAgLfhdOhDAK46ZnWCAKVndrNAwK4r5OaCipKQs8Qpkd25hYiUSafRFyvUGzpZRXvRzfKNuVsC9Js" />
</div>
<div class="centered" id="selectReport">
    <select name="Archives" onchange="javascript:setTimeout(&#39;__doPostBack(\&#39;Archives\&#39;,\&#39;\&#39;)&#39;, 0)" id="Archives">
<option selected="selected" value="Dashboard_2012-May-1">Dashboard_2012-May-1</option>
<option value="Trends">Trends</option>
<option value="Styles">Styles</option>
<option value="Scripts">Scripts</option>
<option value="App_Data">App_Data</option>
<option value="Account">Account</option>

</select>
    <input type="submit" name="viewReport" value="View Report" id="viewReport" />
</div>

<div class="centered" id="buttons">
    <input type="submit" name="saveEdits" value="Save Edits" id="saveEdits" />
    <input type="submit" name="redoEdits" value="Redo Edits" id="redoEdits" />
</div>
```

I must be missing the blindingly obvious but I am stumped.  Any advice is appreciated.

Regards.

Comment: What css is there on #selectReport? And also, what is the width of .centered. (If it is 100% wide, it is pointless to center it. Try putting display:inline-block; on .centered and see if it changes anything.

Comment: What does the DOM inspector in your console show?  It will tell you what CSS is being applied and from where it comes.

Comment: the  example in separate file is different.

Comment: @richard: sorry, typo, I'll fix it.

Comment: It doesn't matter to your problem, but `margin: auto` also applies `auto` to top & bottom which is superfluous.  `margin: 0 auto` is more logical.

Comment: If you want more useful help, post the rendered HTML, not ASP.Net server controls as we have no idea what's actually rendered at runtime.

Comment: @BjarkeCK: There is no CSS on #selectedReport.  I only gave the divs separate ids when I wanted to target them  both individually.  Right now the only CSS is for .centered.

Comment: @SergioTapia: I just added a screenshot of the rendering.

Comment: He meant the rendered HTML _code_.

Comment: @Sparky672: Do you mean the page source?  I thought the image was the rendered HTML.

Comment: Rendered HTML can be viewed in the browser's page source.

Comment: @Sparky672: Thanks.  I'll add it now.

Comment: Thanks for posting the HTML but where is the relevant CSS for the two `div`'s?  There should/could be something in your stylesheet for `#selectReport` and `#buttons` that specifies properties including their `width`.

Comment: @Sparky672: In another comment I posted this link to a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfarmer/ZrdUY/

Comment: All relevant code for your problem example should be posted in the OP.  Otherwise, when the jsFiddle links go dead, the question is useless.  Also, you should not rely on various comments as a supplement to the question; it should be fully self-contained.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer provided by a comment from Kit Grose: http://jsfiddle.net/ZrdUY/1/.

Answer (score 1):

Try giving your divs a fixed width and centering them:

```
.centered {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 60%; // or whatever you need.
}
```

To center a div you usually need to have given it a concrete width.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried it but the first div is still left justified while the second is centered.

Comment: @Kevin: If you want help, post the relevant rendered HTML (not asp.net server controls) and also a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Your div is likely already centred (although if your CSS rules are, literally, just `margin: auto`, they're not doing anything until you specify a `width` on your div). The issue is that the controls inside it (your form fields) are not.

Try adding `text-align: center;` to your `.centered` CSS rules.

Remember input elements are inline elements, meaning they are affected by rules that would apply to text (like `text-align`, `line-height`, `text-indent` etc.).

You can see this for yourself by using some developer tools to inspect what's going on. IE has some, WebKit browsers like Chrome and Safari have them, Firefox has them, Opera does too. With them, you can (in real time) understand how your CSS rules affect layout, and the shape of the elements on the page.

Comment: I actually did put text-align: center because I thought this was necessary for compatibility with IE6.  Strangely it displays perfectly in IE6 but the centering is inconsistent in FF13.

Comment: Also, specifying a width has no effect.

Comment: I suspect there are other factors at play here. Other rules that are applying that prevent standard fixes from working. Developer tools will help you see those, or you could set up a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for it so we can diagnose it for you. Unfortunately we'll need to see the whole CSS file to understand which rules are overriding this one.

Comment: Here is the fiddle minus the central table -- which is large: http://jsfiddle.net/kfarmer/N9kWM/.  The buttons don't show up at all in the fiddle.  Strangely, none of the CSS attributes that I apply to the .centered class affect the display in Firefox but they all display perfectly in IE6.

Comment: @Kevin: they don't show up because you've uploaded the ASP template as opposed to the rendered HTML. When [I update them to the markup you provided](http://jsfiddle.net/ZrdUY/1/) above it works (in Safari and Firefox alike). I also removed the auto margins and fixed widths because it's clearly not what you need. Does that page not centre the fields for you?

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation.  Clearly I misunderstood the use of the fiddle.  Your rendering is what the page looks like in IE6 -- centered and padded.  In Firefox 13.0.1 there is no padding, the first set of buttons are centered and the second set of buttons are aligned to the left of the first set.  I have tried every attribute there is and nothing seems to have an effect on how this renders in Firefox.

Comment: Whoops.  I must have been loading a cached page.  I just refreshed and everything is fine with the changes you made to my CSS.  Thanks a million!